# Regular expression for certain amount of characters

Tags: regex, textwrangler

I'm trying to change a lot of URLs with TextWrangler, those ending with `m.htm` should lose the `m`, but only if the total number of characters in the filename is 7. Those with fewer characters should not be changed.

I've tried

```
/.*?{7}m.htm/
```

but it doesn't work...

What is the solution?

Comment: Can you provide 2 urls you want to change (with the replacements) and two you don't want to change?

Comment: here is the syntax for the four urls, first and fourth need to be changed, second and third need no changes

<a href="google.com/urzadjm.htm">testM</a>
<a href="google.com/brblam.htm">test</a>
<a href="google.com/rlfzao.htm">test</a>
<a href="google.com/vlabgam.htm">testM</a>

Comment: Do you already have the URL at your disposition, or you have all the <a> block to parse?

Comment: this is the syntax from the file I'm working on, unfortunately I can't work with just a list of plain urls (if that's what you mean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
href="([^"]*)\/(.{6})m.htm([^"]*)"
```

Meaning : `href="` followed by any non `"` character until a `/` (the latest the better: greedy) then 6 character followed by a `m`, then any non `"` character.

By

```
href="\1\/\2.htm\3"
```

Meaning :

```
\1 = [^"]*
\2 = .{6}
\3 = [^"]*
```

Example

```
<a href="google.com/foo/bar/urzadjm.htm">testM</a> 
\1 : google.com/foo/bar
\2 : urzadj
\3 : <empty>
```

If files can be `htm` and `php`, I suggest to replace `.htm` by `(.htm|.php)` (!Warning to back-references change in numbers!)

Comment: this does find the strings I want, but it doesn't remove the m, it just pastes the same string...

Comment: Oh my bad!! I made a mistake with the parenthesis. Corrected.

Comment: it seems I got it, had to move the m out of the second group! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
/\b.{6}m\.htm/
```

That is, starting on the word boundary, followed by any 6 symbols, followed by m.htm.

Comment: What flavour of regex does TextWrangler undestand?

Comment: How can I find it out? I haven't installed any add-ons or anything, if that helps...